# Using WScript.CreateObject in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, shell

I have been researching using

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

to act as a means to create a multi-line, hover-over, 5-second pop-up for a command button on a Userform. From everything I can figure this should be working fine, but it's giving a *"Variable not defined"* error. On debugging it highlights `"WScript"` in the `Set` line as the issue.

```
Private Sub CB1604A_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
                              ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

Dim WshShell
Dim BTN
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

BTN = WshShell.PopUp("What do you want to do?", 5)

Select Case BTN
    Case 6
        WScript.Echo "Do it now."
    Case 7
        WScript.Echo "Do it later."
    Case -1
        WScript.Echo "Cancel all actions?"
End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add a reference to `WScript` to use its `CreateObject`  - but you don't need to; instead use VBA's `CreateObject` to create an instance of `.Shell`:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
BTN = WshShell.PopUp("What do you want to do?", 5)
```

And subsequently use `MsgBox` instead of `WScript.Echo`:

```
...
MsgBox "Do it now."
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and had a few glitches. It created almost 200 msgbox's in the time it took me to move on and off the command button and the popup never displayed.

Comment: That's because you are using the MouseMove event, so it fires every time your mouse moves within the bounds of the control. Same thing would happen with your original code if you hadn't run into the missing reference problem.